# Responsiveness off a website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to start by telling you that I don't want you to give me code, nor do I want you to do any other work for me.

My question is(and maybe it is a really easy one): I cannot find a tutorial for creating a website which the menubar will transform from this:
[image]
To this:
[image]

So when you scroll down it will just compress into a smaller menu, but still stay at the top of the website.

If you don't know what I mean go to a YouTube channel and scroll down, you will see that the menu slightly changes but still stays on top.

If any of you have a tutorial for this I would be happy to recieve a link. I couldn't find one since I don't know how to call this. (Advanced tutorials also welcome)

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: If you can just name how this is called I will search for it myself

Comment: look for "sticky header"

Comment: [try this one](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-sticky-position/)

Comment: Yes thank you I will delete this question now since it is against the "rules"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if that is what you want... We can call it a sticky element.

There is a good library to do things like that in jQuery:

- StickyJS - http://stickyjs.com/

You can find many other libraries [here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2015/05/14-useful-jquery-plugins-for-creating-sticky-elements).